# PayPal Subscribe button: Error: Cannot read property 'subscription' of undefined

Tags: paypal

I am working on the integration of a PayPal subscription. Since I have a user-defined plan and I've to create a plan accordingly, which I've created using the following curl request in getplan.php:

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/plans",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\r\n  \"product_id\": \"PROD-65T41140NK6579847\",\r\n  \"name\": \"Video Streaming Service Plan\",\r\n  \"description\": \"Video Streaming Service basic plan\",\r\n  \"status\": \"ACTIVE\",\r\n  \"billing_cycles\": [\r\n    {\r\n      \"frequency\": {\r\n        \"interval_unit\": \"MONTH\",\r\n        \"interval_count\": 1\r\n      },\r\n      \"tenure_type\": \"TRIAL\",\r\n      \"sequence\": 1,\r\n      \"total_cycles\": 2,\r\n      \"pricing_scheme\": {\r\n        \"fixed_price\": {\r\n          \"value\": \"3\",\r\n          \"currency_code\": \"USD\"\r\n        }\r\n      }\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"frequency\": {\r\n        \"interval_unit\": \"MONTH\",\r\n        \"interval_count\": 1\r\n      },\r\n      \"tenure_type\": \"TRIAL\",\r\n      \"sequence\": 2,\r\n      \"total_cycles\": 3,\r\n      \"pricing_scheme\": {\r\n        \"fixed_price\": {\r\n          \"value\": \"6\",\r\n          \"currency_code\": \"USD\"\r\n        }\r\n      }\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"frequency\": {\r\n        \"interval_unit\": \"MONTH\",\r\n        \"interval_count\": 1\r\n      },\r\n      \"tenure_type\": \"REGULAR\",\r\n      \"sequence\": 3,\r\n      \"total_cycles\": 12,\r\n      \"pricing_scheme\": {\r\n        \"fixed_price\": {\r\n          \"value\": \"10\",\r\n          \"currency_code\": \"USD\"\r\n        }\r\n      }\r\n    }\r\n  ],\r\n  \"payment_preferences\": {\r\n    \"auto_bill_outstanding\": true,\r\n    \"setup_fee\": {\r\n      \"value\": \"10\",\r\n      \"currency_code\": \"USD\"\r\n    },\r\n    \"setup_fee_failure_action\": \"CONTINUE\",\r\n    \"payment_failure_threshold\": 3\r\n  },\r\n  \"taxes\": {\r\n    \"percentage\": \"10\",\r\n    \"inclusive\": false\r\n  }\r\n}",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "authorization: Bearer A21AAJd7f6oo6_Inozxc4JfgLaPvnlU_-3kYw_8JdRLnjsJ-aiRe_ZgRaZWBnwd4Oh8WZvwBbvyI0QRHGY3pRVbWGgnV8kY1g",
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "content-type: application/json",
    "postman-token: 4ed388a2-e0eb-39f2-a624-51291f549960",
    "prefer: return=representation"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

I've successfully received the plan id by the above curl request.

```
 <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=<client-id>&currency=USD&intent=subscription&commit=false&vault=true&disable-funding=credit,card"></script>

<script>
    paypal.Buttons({
        createSubscription: function() {
          return fetch('getplan.php', {
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
              'content-type': 'application/json'
            },
          }).then(function(res) {
            return res.json();
          }).then(function(data,actions) {
            return actions.subscription.create({
               'plan_id': data.id
            });
          });
        },
    onApprove: function(data, actions) {

    alert('You have successfully created subscription ' + data.subscriptionID);

  }
  }).render('#paypal-button');
</script>
<div id="paypal-button"></div>
```

But the console is giving the error "Cannot read property 'subscription' of undefined". If I manually enter the plan_id (which I've created) in creating the subscription function it gives me  Error: Cannot read property 'subscription' of undefined.

Please help!

Comment: Show the exact code which caused the error you're talking about, please. It's unclear how this php and JavaScript are connected.

Comment: Entering it manually ought to work. Is `client-id=<clinet-id>` a sandbox client-id ? Post your actual code with your actual sandbox client id (it is not sensitive) and with your actual plan ID, please.

Comment: @PrestonPHX and ADyson PHX I've pasted the actual code. I have successfully received the plan in my create_subscription function but still, it is giving me the same error.

Comment: Can't be of any help without knowing what data.id is here

Comment: @PrestonPHX I am getting data.id from the getplan.php file, and it is successfully returning the plan id. Please use P-4HT71832RA456781CMBEHFVA plan ID if it is not returning for you. Thanks!

Comment: Of course it's not returning for us, a local path `getplan.php` doesn't exist anywhere for anyone but you wherever you're testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, spotted your problem. `actions` is undefined because you have it as a parameter in the wrong place.

```
    createSubscription: function(data, actions) {
          return fetch('getplan.php', {
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
              'content-type': 'application/json'
            },
          }).then(function(res) {
            return res.json();
          }).then(function(serverData) {
            return actions.subscription.create({
               'plan_id': serverData.id
            });
          });
        },
```

This is a strange pattern to be coding, though -- if you are doing a fetch to your server in createSubscription, you may as well create the subscription server-side (getsubscription.php or whatever) and return the subscription id rather than a plan id.

Comment: Thank you @Preston but according to the PayPal doc we need to enter the plan id in actions.subscription.create function.  https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/integrate/#create-the-subscription

Comment: For a basic integration with no server, yes. Since you have a server and are calling it anyway, no reason to do `actions.subscription.create` on the client side.

Comment: Now I am getting Uncaught Error: Expected an subscription id to be passed to createSubscription. Generally we get the subscription id when we completed the subscription.

Comment: Well I'm not sure what your code is doing now, but you need to pass an `id` of one you create. This is the API: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions_create

Comment: I was getting the plan_id from getplan.php file and passing it to the js file. Now, I've received the subscription id through the api link which you sent  which is I-FYPARBAC86J3, and passed this id to actions.subscription.create function of JS but it is giving me the same error "Error: Cannot read property 'subscription' of undefined"